# Upgrade to Android Studio 3.0 and images not showing

Tags: android, android-drawable

I just upgraded to Android Studio 3.0, after a several month hiatus from Android development.  The app compiles and runs fine, but all the images on the app are not showing on the screen.  That is, the layout is fine except that every image that should be shown is not showing.  The labels, text, and layout are in their proper place.  It's just that every place there should be an image, it just isn't drawn.
The Drawable folder looks fine.  All images are there and the code properly references each with `R.drawable.icon_large_foo`.
Any ideas what might be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to clean build cache and/or gradle cache?

Comment: is that a debug version or release signed version?

Comment: If you are using vector images then you Need to change the fill Color of Vector Images  "#_____" hash code format  you can't use the "@drawable/ImageName".

Comment: @matrix: Yes, both "invalidate cache" and "clean build"

Comment: @tamtom: This is a debug build.  We've been using debug for over a year with no problems.

Comment: @ChandraShekharKaushik : These are all .png files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I never discovered why only a few of the .png images would display when the layout was inflated and displayed, I did find a workaround.  I simply repopulated the same images programmatically from the main code.  The images then show up just fine.  It is worth noting that these are the exact same resources that were placed in the Android Studio layout editor.